# Как реализовать в Телеграм-боте функции парсинга с открытых каналов на Python?

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

Есть Телеграм-бот, написанный на Telebot. Он принимает от пользователя:

1. Список открытых (новостных) телеграм-каналов. Сохраняет их в БД (PostgreSQL).
2. Список ключевых слов и фраз. Сохраняет их БД.
3. Дату, с которой надо начинать мониторинг каналов. Сохраняет её в БД.

Как реализовать функцию, что Бот изучал заданные каналы с заданной даты после запуска, а далее каждые 10 минут проверял наличие новых сообщений и в случае совпадения пересылал их пользователю, который его активировал.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.